# Pressure vs electric conductivity in solids

Tags: solid-state-chemistry, pressure, conductivity

If we apply pressure to a solid, does it change its electric conductivity? I am asking this because in 2020 they announced a superconductor at room temperature but under a pressure of 3/4 of the pressure in the core of the Earth. Decreasing pressure decreased the critical temperature. So I was wondering if pressure affects the electric conductivity of other materials as well? And if it does is there an intuitive explanation, why?

Comment: Superconductivity is almost unrelated to ordinary conductivity. As for the pressure that great, sure, it changes the structure of compounds and pretty much all their properties.

Comment: Regardless of the change in the structure of compounds does it influence the motion of electrons(or holes) or not?

Comment: https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/83355/what-is-chemical-pressure

Comment: Well, a change in structure (crystal type) will definitely change the band structure. Further, even in the same crystal structure hydrostatic pressure does change the inter-atomic spacings which also changes the band structure. For example, with increasing pressure the band gap of silicon decreases which changes the intrinsic carrier concentrations at a given temperature.

Comment: This is a very rich area. If you Google "effect of pressure on electrical conductivity" you'll find many articles on the subject. With some materials the conductivity goes up with pressure, with others it goes down, and with still others it goes in one direction and then reverses. And the conductivity is much more pressure-sensitive in some materials than others. So you can infer from this that the mechanism by which pressure affects conductivity is very material-specific. Alas, I don't know the field well enough to offer a particularly nice specific example to illustrate the phenomenon.

Comment: Does a change in pressure changes the electric conductivity depending on the material (conductor,semiconductor-insulator) , just like temperature does(for conductors increased temperature->increased resistivity and for semiconductors and  insulators increased temperature->decreased resistivity) or is it more complex?

Comment: @JonCuster in the case of silicon decrease of the interatomic spacing means increase in energy of the valence band which decreases band gap?

Comment: @MissMulan - the bands change, yes. See https://journals.aps.org/prb/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevB.40.12516 as a place to jump into the literature.

Comment: Increase in pressure decreases the interatomic distance which increases the energy of each covalent bond->valence band.By why is the energy of the conduction band increased?